# Keep value in select after navigation with NgbNav

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm having a problem that I'm not able to understand, I have a customizable component of the select type, it apparently works correctly and is storing the value of the option in the formControl through formControlName, but when changing tabs of the ngbNav the select simply stops displaying the value that was previously selected, I have already debugged the writeValue and obj correctly, but nothing is assigned to the select again.

[Componet NgbNav](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/nav/api#NgbNavCha)
HTML code

```
<ul ngbNav #nav="ngbNav" class="nav-tabs">
            <li ngbNavItem>
                <button ngbNavLink>Dados do representante</button>
                <ng-template ngbNavContent>
                    <form [formGroup]="representativeForm">
                        <section>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                                    <b-select-custom id="sex" name="sex" [options]="sexs" propertyOption="description"
                                        label="Sexo" formControlName="sex" [isValid]="representativeForm.controls['sex'].errors?.['required']
                                        && representativeForm.controls['sex'].touched"></b-select-custom>
                                        
                                    <!-- <select name="sex" id="sex" formControlName="sex">
                                        <option value="" selected></option>
                                        <option *ngFor="let sex of sexs" [ngValue]="sex">{{sex.description}}</option>
                                    </select> -->

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                                    <b-select-custom id="peopleType" name="peopleType" [options]="peopleTypes"
                                        propertyOption="description" label="Tipo de pessoa" formControlName="peopletype"
                                        [isValid]="representativeForm.controls['peopletype'].errors?.['required']
                                        && representativeForm.controls['peopletype'].touched"
                                        (ngModelChange)="filterDocumentTypeByPeopleTypeId($event)">
                                    </b-select-custom>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                        <section class="mt-3">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                                    <b-select-custom id="documentType" name="documentType" label="Tipo de documento"
                                        formControlName="documenttype" [options]="documentTypesFiltered"
                                        propertyOption="description" [isValid]="representativeForm.controls['documenttype'].errors?.['required']
                                        && representativeForm.controls['documenttype'].touched"></b-select-custom>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    </form>
                </ng-template>
            </li>
            <li ngbNavItem>
                <button ngbNavLink (click)="loadStates()">Dados do Endereço</button>
                <ng-template ngbNavContent>

                </ng-template>
            </li>
            <li ngbNavItem>
                <button ngbNavLink>Dados de usuário</button>
                <ng-template ngbNavContent>
                    <button (click)="onSubmit()">Cadastrar</button>
                </ng-template>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="ngbNavOutlet" [ngbNavOutlet]="nav"></div>
```

TS code

```
protected sexs: Array<Sex> = [{id:1, "Feminino"},{id:2, description: "Masculino"}];
representativeForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({ sex: new FormControl<string | null>(null, [Validators.required])});
```

component

HTML code

```
<div class="container-select-wrapper w-100">
    <div class="select-wrapper w-100 d-flex align-items-center" [ngClass]="{'has-value':hasValue}">
        <select [id]="id" (change)="onSelectOption($event)" class="w-100" [disabled]="disabled" (blur)="onTouched()">
            <option [value]="" selected></option>
            <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option | json">{{option[propertyOption]}}
            </option>
        </select>
        <label [for]="id" class="floating-label">{{label}}</label>
        <img id="iconAlert" *ngIf="isValid" title="Campo obrigatório" src="\assets\icons\alert.svg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

TS code

```
import { Component, forwardRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALIDATORS, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, Validator } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'b-select-custom',
  templateUrl: './select-custom.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-custom.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => SelectCustomComponent),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => SelectCustomComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class SelectCustomComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
  @Input() id!: string;
  @Input() label!: string;
  @Input() options!: any[];
  @Input() formControlName!: string;
  @Input() propertyOption!: string;
  @Input() isValid!: boolean;

  selectedOption: any;
  onChange: any;
  onTouched: any;
  hasValue: boolean = false;
  disabled: boolean = false;

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.selectedOption = obj;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  validate(): any {
    return null;
  }

  onSelectOption(option: any): void {
    const select = (option.target as HTMLSelectElement)
    this.selectedOption = JSON.parse(select.value);
    this.hasValue = this.selectedOption != "";

    this.onChange(this.selectedOption);
    this.onTouched();
  }


}
```

I've tried using ngModel, ngValue and other failed attempts.